# User registration and authentication in PHP and PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**I share all the full code, and hopefully someone will serve you or help me improve.**

**Please criticize as thoroughly as possible for the smallest thing possible as it will be very useful for me.**

I'm trying to create a safe and easy system to change for future projects. I am aware that it takes many more options (check email, access attempts, notification by email, etc.) at the moment this is what I have. Is it even safe now?

I want to continue working on, but I am not sure 100% if I'm on the right track or you need to add or remove some code (I like as short as possible).

What opinion can I give? I'll let the files and also a link to GitHub so you can read better: https://github.com/GePraxa/login

#### File **login.sql**

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

-- Database: `login`

-- Table structure for table `users`
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `user_email` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `user_pass` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `joining_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

#### File **config.php**

```
<?php
    // Other settings
    session_start();

    // Connect to the database
    class Database {
        private $host = "localhost";
        private $db_name = "login";
        private $username = "root";
        private $password = "";
        public $conn;

        public function dbConnection() {
            $this->conn = null;
            try {
                $this->conn = new PDO(
                    "mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name,
                    $this->username,
                    $this->password);
                $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            }
            catch(PDOException $exception) {
                echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
            }
            return $this->conn;
        }
    }

    // Functions for managing users
    class USER {
        private $conn;

        public function __construct() {
            $database = new Database();
            $db = $database->dbConnection();
            $this->conn = $db;
        }

        public function runQuery($sql) {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
            return $stmt;
        }

        public function register($uname, $umail, $upass) {
            try {
                $new_password = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(user_name,user_email,user_pass) VALUES(:uname, :umail, :upass)");
                $stmt->bindparam(":uname", $uname);
                $stmt->bindparam(":umail", $umail);
                $stmt->bindparam(":upass", $new_password);
                $stmt->execute();
                return $stmt;
            }
            catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        public function doLogin($uname,$umail,$upass) {
            try {
                $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT user_id, user_name, user_email, user_pass FROM users WHERE user_name=:uname OR user_email=:umail ");
                $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname, ':umail'=>$umail));
                $userRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                if($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
                    if(password_verify($upass, $userRow['user_pass'])) {
                        $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['user_id'];
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        public function is_loggedin() {
            if(isset($_SESSION['user_session'])) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        public function redirect($url) {
            header("Location: $url");
            exit;
        }

        public function doLogout() {
            unset($_SESSION['user_session']);
            return true;
        }
    }
?>
```

#### File **index.php**

```
<?php
    require_once('assets/config.php');

    // If you are not logged, redirects to login page.
    $session = new USER();
    if(!$session->is_loggedin()) {
        $session->redirect('login.php');
    }

    $auth_user = new USER();
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];
    $stmt = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=:user_id");
    $stmt->execute(array(":user_id"=>$user_id));
    $userRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Welcome</title>
        <link href="assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Hello, <?php echo $userRow['user_name'];?>! - <a href="logout.php">Logout</a></h1>
            <hr/>
            <p>This is the user area, this content is private.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### File **login.php**

```
<?php
    require_once('assets/config.php');
    $login = new USER();

    if($login->is_loggedin()!="") {
        $login->redirect('index.php');
    }

    if(isset($_POST['btn-login'])) {
        $uname = strip_tags($_POST['txt_uname_email']);
        $umail = strip_tags($_POST['txt_uname_email']);
        $upass = strip_tags($_POST['txt_password']);

        if($login->doLogin($uname,$umail,$upass)) {
            $login->redirect('index.php');
        }
        else {
            $error = "Wrong Details!";
        }
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Login</title>
        <link href="assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Login or <a href="register.php">Register</a></h1>
            <hr/>
            <div class="error">
                <?php
                    if(isset($error)) {
                        echo "<p class='error'>$error</p>";
                    }
                    if(isset($_GET['joined'])) {
                        echo "<p class='success'>Successfully registered please login</p>";
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
            <form method="post" id="login-form">
                <input type="text" name="txt_uname_email" placeholder="Username or Email"/>
                <input type="password" name="txt_password" placeholder="Password" />
                <button type="submit" name="btn-login">Login</button>
             </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### File **register.php**

```
<?php
    require_once('assets/config.php');

    $user = new USER();

    if($user->is_loggedin()!="") {
        $user->redirect('index.php');
    }

    if(isset($_POST['btn-signup'])) {
        $uname = strip_tags($_POST['txt_uname']);
        $umail = strip_tags($_POST['txt_umail']);
        $upass = strip_tags($_POST['txt_upass']);

        if($uname=="") {
            $error[] = "Provide username!";
        }
        else if($umail=="") {
            $error[] = "Provide email!";
        }
        else if(!filter_var($umail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $error[] = 'Please enter a valid email address!';
        }
        else if($upass == "") {
            $error[] = "Provide password!";
        }
        else if(strlen($upass) < 6){
            $error[] = "Password must be atleast 6 characters!";
        }
        else {
            try {
                $stmt = $user->runQuery("SELECT user_name, user_email FROM users WHERE user_name=:uname OR user_email=:umail");
                $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname, ':umail'=>$umail));
                $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                if($row['user_name'] == $uname) {
                    $error[] = "Sorry username already taken!";
                }
                else if($row['user_email'] == $umail) {
                    $error[] = "Sorry email id already taken!";
                }
                else {
                    if($user->register($uname, $umail, $upass)){
                        $user->redirect('login.php?joined');
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Register</title>
        <link href="assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Register or <a href="login.php">Login</a></h1>
            <hr/>
            <?php
                if(isset($error)) {
                    foreach($error as $error) {
                        echo "<p class='error'>$error</p>";
                    }
                }
            ?>
            <form method="post">
                <input type="text" name="txt_uname" placeholder="Username" value="<?php if(isset($error)){echo $uname;}?>" />
                <input type="text" name="txt_umail" placeholder="Email" value="<?php if(isset($error)){echo $umail;}?>" />
                <input type="password" name="txt_upass" placeholder="Password" />
                <button type="submit" name="btn-signup">Register</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### File **logout.php**

```
<?php
    require_once('assets/config.php');

    $user_logout = new USER();
    $user_logout->doLogout();
    $user_logout->redirect('index.php');
?>
```

Comment: so at present its working good? might be better at codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Ghost Thanks for the information right now I share there.

Comment: @Ghost He asks me wait 40 minutes to repost, you could comment me here, you think?

Comment: [Please do not catch exceptions to report them](https://phpdelusions.net/delusion/try-catch)

Comment: [Cross posted on Code Review.](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/140824/user-registration-and-authentication-in-php-and-pdo)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question belongs to codereview.stackexchange.com